# Nuxt. При переходе на несуществующую страницу сайта status code 500

Tags: маршрутизация, nuxt.js, http-status-code-500

Проект на Vue 2 + Nuxt 2.15.7. При переходе по несуществующему на сайте адресу происходит перенаправление на страницу error как и должно быть, но во вкладке Network инструмента разработчика отображается status code 500, вместо которого я ожидаю получить 404. В консоли у объекта ошибки есть поле code, значение которого 404, и также statusCode, значение которого равен 500. Что мне необходимо сделать, чтобы при переходе на несуществующий адрес statusCode был равен 404?

**Выяснил дополнительный момент:** 500 ошибка приходит если глубина адреса совпадает с динамическим роутингом, то есть https://site.io/blog и https://site.io/blog/name. Если за пределами роутинга (https://site.io/blog/name/zxc), то 404 приходит как надо

Comment: У Вас сервер (API какое-то) отправляет ошибку 500 в ответ? Если да, то 404 превратится в 500

Comment: @Vladimir Gonchar, спасибо Вам за внимание. Была проблема, связанная с запутанной логикой подгрузки данных с сервера и неправильной обработке ошибки. В результате вместо ожидаемой 404 сервер выдавал 500. Сейчас проблема решена, но мой вопрос и его решение вряд ли принесут кому-то пользу, уж слишком специфичная была проблема